# Calendar in date exposed filter?

Tags: views, datetime

I'm looking for a Views exposed filter for node creation date that:

- Shows a calendar (not popup)
- Highlights days corresponding to existing node creation dates
- Allows to click those days to see nodes created on that day

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: If I interpret you correctly, you're looking for something that looks like the jquery ui calendar popup, but is 1) Always open, and 2) Pulls in data from the site as well?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Calendar module to perform what I wanted. But since I was not using the stock Calendar view, I had to customize some things. Basically, Calendar Block and Calendar Period together achieve the display I need. I had to alter these plugins to show them in Views UI - for some reason the module authors decided to hide them :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_plugins_alter().
 */ 
function liveblog_views_plugins_alter(&$plugins) {
  unset($plugins['display']['calendar_block']['no ui']);
  unset($plugins['display']['calendar_period']['no ui']);
}
```

I also had to patch the module to avoid a hard-coded condition, as explained in this issue I submitted: http://drupal.org/node/1409520.

Based on this, I edited my view to add a Calendar Block display, with a Date argument, and a Calendar Period display attached to the Calendar Block, with the same argument.  That was it!

Answer (score 0):

This issue will help you out
http://drupal.org/node/502824

Answer (score 0):

You could use views and date or date picker module like [datepick](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker)

> This module extends the date_popup module (from the date project) to provide a JQuery UI inline datepicker, rather than a popup out of a textfield. For an example of this see http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

There are 3 ways to use this module.

Using the Views filter handler for Date filters.
Using the Form API, by setting #type to "datepicker",

With views you can use jQueryUI Date picker [see here for a tutorial.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2481343)

[image: Drupal views calender picker]